# transferring files over two-hop SSH session

Tags: ssh

I have a Linux box at work that I often log in to from home. The Linux box is on an internal network, but there's a box that spans both networks, so I can log in like so:

```
ssh -tA username@bridge.work.com ssh username@10.10.10.130
```

I have a couple of files sitting in ~/tmp that I would like to copy to my local machine. (let's call them ~/tmp/file1 ~/tmp/file2 and ~/tmp/file3 for the sake of argument)

I've seen something like this work:

```
ssh -tA username@bridge.work.com ssh username@10.10.10.130 'tar cf - ~/tmp/file*' | tar xf -
```

This would tar the files on the remote machine, send the result to stdout, then pipe the results to a local tar, which was unpacking data on local stdin.

Doesn't work:

On the remote machine, if I run

```
tar cf - tmp/file* | md5sum
f1b776364c10dfc20500f228399a7c63  -
```

From the local machine:

```
ssh -tA username@bridge.work.com ssh username@10.10.10.130 'tar cf - ~/tmp/file*' | md5sum
bc7436c9771ee2b4978ffd29b8b7ed36  -
```

I'm assuming that this is probably a byte ordering snafu across the network... I was eventually able to get around it by uuencoding the file, catting it across the network then uudecoding it locally... for some reason I couldn't get the syntax correct to be able to tar | uuencode on the remote side and uudecode | untar on the local side.

I'm looking for a good way of doing this all in one step; preferably something that I can wrap in a shell function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the SSH ProxyCommand configuration option to in the configuration on your client.  This allows you to make a direct connection to the destination.

```
Host remotebox
    ProxyCommand /usr/bin/ssh username@bridge.work.com "/bin/netcat -w 1 10.10.10.130 22"
    User username
```

scp remotebox:file local

Comment: Hmm. I'm getting 
bash: /bin/netcat: No such file or directory

Comment: By the way, I really like this solution... I've never played with the 'ProxyCommand' directive, and it's got me curious. I would have marked this as the accepted answer had this worked out of the box. Thanks for the education.

Comment: netcat needs to be installed on your bridge box.  It is a pretty common tool.

Comment: Aha. It's installed as /usr/bin/netcat on the bridge box.

Comment: ... and the scp worked. Cheers!

Comment: to avoid being prompted for a password, you'll have to have the public key for your local machine installed on both the bridge and the target machines, and use the `ssh -A` switch inside the `ProxyCommand`

Answer (score 6):

You can set up port forwarding. Change your inital command to be:

```
ssh -TA username@bridge.work.com -L 2222:10.10.10.130:22
```

Then ignore this command. Open a new terminal and run one of:

```
ssh -p 2222 username_for_10.10.10.130@127.0.0.1
scp -P 2222 username_for_10.10.10.130@127.0.0.1 remote_file local_file
```

Whenever your local system gets a connection request on its localhost IP address port 2222, the SSH command that you ran first will forward that on to the remote system and have it issue a connection request to 10.10.10.130. This is all specified by the -L switch.

Answer (score 4):

Byte ordering only applies to such things as IP headers (which have four-byte-sized addresses as a single unit), but does not affect higher-layer protocols which work with 8-bit bytes only -- IP, TCP, and SSH all guarantee that you receive data exactly as it was sent, byte by byte.

The problem is caused by the `-t` option to the first `ssh`. It forces allocation of a pseudo-tty for the first connection, which is only necessary for terminals (and terminal emulators) and will mangle certain data during the transfer. In particular, carriage returns (0x0D) will be automatically inserted before every linefeed (0x0A).

Just remove the `-t` option, and you will have a clean channel for transferring binary data.

Comment: This worked... I got a good tar file on the local side. Ironically, the difference in md5sum was a red herring: every time that I ran 'tar zcf - /home/username/tmp/file* | md5sum' on the remote machine, I got a different md5sum.

Comment: @Barton: No, it wasn't. Your test in the question was done using plain tar, which always outputs the same data for the same directory and results in the same hash as well. (Your data was being corrupted by SSH.) The one in your comment, however, compresses the output with gzip (the `z`) option, which *embeds the current timestamp* in the gzip header, causing different hashes every time.

Comment: Fascinating. Why is it that this is only the case when tar gzips a file? If I create 'asdf.txt' and run 'gzip -c asdf.txt | md5sum' twice in a row, I'll get the same checksum... oh... I get it... the gzip header holds the mtime of the file being gzipped... if that's a freshly created tar file, different mtime.

Comment: @Barton: In this case, the "mtime" is actually the current system time. When you are using gzip via `tar -z`, there is no "tar file"; there is only an anonymous stream that tar outputs and gzip compresses.

Comment: I also found that `-t` was messing up the stream. The problem is, I want to define a shell script or alias as `ssh -[t]A bridge.work.com ssh 10.10.10.130` and I need two of them, for interactive and non-interactive each!

Comment: @musiphil: Shell functions or scripts could be used: `somehost() { local t=${1:+"-t"}; ssh $t -A bridge.work.com "ssh $t 10.10.10.130 $*"; }` A better option, however, would be to update your `~/.ssh/config` to use bridge.work.com as a "ProxyCommand", like this: `Host 10.10.10.*` (newline) `ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p bridge.work.com`

Comment: @grawity: Thanks. I tried to use `ProxyCommand`, but in my case it seems that the system-wide `ProxyCommand` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` takes effect and my setting in `~/.ssh/config` is ignored.

Comment: @grawity: Actually, it was the system-wide `UseProxyIf` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` that was preventing my `ProxyCommand` to take effect; `UseProxyIf true` solved this.