# Screen ssh tunnel doesn't seem to work

Tags: gnu-screen

I've got an entry in my .screenrc that goes like this:

```
screen ssh -nNfL 2200:remotehost:22 tunnelhost
screen -t 'Launcher' ssh localhost -p 2200
```

This seems to start the tunnel session in screen no. 0 but then only opens a new tab on the tunnel host (screen no. 1), not the host I'm trying to tunnel to.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here. If you are just trying to tunnel through an intermeditate box, then why not simply setup a config file and the [ProxyCommand](http://superuser.com/a/345373/2057) option?

Comment: IIRC I need netcat to be installed and these are corporate boxes that are locked down.  I can't install any software on them.

Comment: Any idea what version of SSH is on the client and intermediate box?  If they are both recent enough there is another alternative.

Comment: looks like OpenSSH_4.3p2 on both

Comment: Ugh, that is ancient.  You need [5.4](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-5.4) for netcat mode (`-W`)