# SSHing into a machine over SSH and running a command - how?

Tags: bash, ssh

I can run a command on a remote server like this:

```
➜  ~ ssh johnh@somehost.example.com hostname
somehost-001
```

But from somehost.example.com I'd like to SSH into another machine on it's local network and run the hostname command on that - but all from the comfort of a single command on my local machine, not an interactive terminal.

Is there a way to do this without having to run a script on the 1st remote system - eg just from a local command? I couldn't get my head around the syntax.

Local -> Remote1 -> Remote2

Comment: This may be the answer.. https://superuser.com/questions/345316/transferring-files-over-two-hop-ssh-session

Comment: Forward traffic to Remote2 through an ssh tunnel?